# Python Regular expression to match printing pages and their range

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regular expression that matches any print page specifications (ex: **6, 1-6, 6:4, 10-20/3**)

```
^([1-9]\d*)((?<=\d)[-]|[:]?)((?<=-|:)?[1-9]\d*)?(?:(?<=)([/]?))([1-9]\d*)?$
```

and I have it so that it currently matches: ex: **2048-4096/100 , 15:10/3**

However, my regular expression also matches **5/3** when **/** should only follow a colon or dash, and some digits, like **2048-4096/100**

In the empty positive lookbehind in the above expression I've tried:
`(?:(?<=[:|-]\d)([/]?))`
but that causes all my tests to fail, resulting in no matches. I've also tried `(?:(?<=[:|-]\d*)([/]?))` but quantifiers are not allowed in the lookbehind.

What can I put in the empty positive lookbehind to make it so that it will check if a **:** or **-** and digits are before the **/**?

Comment: What is the purpose of `(?<=[-:])?`? If you require something optionally, just remove this lookbehind.

Comment: *but quantifiers are not allowed in the lookbehind.* built-in module `re` limitation is that lookbehind must be fixed-width, if you need variable length lookbehind and allowed to use external module, take look at [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

Comment: I just realized this problem, as well. I put that there to match just a number (6, 3, 1000) but it created another problem: 5: gets matched when it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^([1-9]\d*)(?:([-:])([1-9]\d*)(?:(/)([1-9]\d*))?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZrIv8F/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([1-9]\d*)` - Group 1: a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
- `(?:([-:])([1-9]\d*)(?:(/)([1-9]\d*))?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `([-:])` - Group 2: `-` or `:`
  - `([1-9]\d*)` - Group 3: a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
  - `(?:(/)([1-9]\d*))?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `(/)` - Group 4: `/`
    - `([1-9]\d*)` - Group 5: a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
- `$`  - end of string.

I kept all groups intact, but at least `(/)` group is redundant as the pattern is fixed as `/`.

Comment: Ahh, I see where I went wrong. It seems I was overcomplicating the task by insisting to use a lookaround. I removed the parantheses from (/) because I need the expression to be done within 4 groups, and your solution still matches. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @newbiecoder11 Right, lookarounds  in cases similar to this one are only necessary when the regex part on the left is optional, and you only want to match the subsequent pattern if the left part was matched. This is used in live input validation only.

Comment: Noted.  For your expression 5: and 5- still match when it should not, and I immediately thought to use a positive look ahead for digits before matching the : or -, but now I am assuming I should not?

Comment: @newbiecoder11 `5:` and `5-` [are NOT matched](https://regex101.com/r/ZrIv8F/3) with my posted regex. Please copy/paste the one in the post.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I must have unknowingly edited something.. My apologies.